# SQL, One id with different values in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Here is my query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.phone
FROM tablename t
```

It results in duplicate IDs because in one column there are two or more different values in it.

```
ID   Phone
1    540-500-5000
1    540-888-8888
2    340-600-6000
2    340-777-7777
3    210-200-2000
4    950-600-6000
4    950-444-4444
```

I want to select just the first phone for each `ID`, in order to avoid duplicated rows just because there are two or more phones under the same `ID`.

Desired output:

```
ID   Phone
1    540-500-5000
2    340-600-6000
3    210-200-2000
4    950-600-6000
```

Comment: What determines "First" phone?  Any ol'e random one? Is there a date time, the max, min?  Order of records in a table can be random.  So saying First in this result means you're willing to accept random as first can and does vary.

Comment: How do you know which is "first"?

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2839c7/1/0):

```
SELECT t.id, MIN(t.phone)
FROM tablename t
GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, MIN(phone) MinIsTheFirst
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID
```

Just having fun with the word "FIRST"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select ID, MIN(Phone)
from tablename
group by ID
```

This will give you what you want if you don't care which phone is returned.  If you have a way of determining the first phone, we can adjust.